# Remove the text box attribute in Grid view when user clicks on next row

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Hi all i have a written a code to highlight the `Row colour` and also the `text-box back ground colour` when user clicks on grid view row. But i would like to clear the applied colour  for text box when user clicks on the next row.

This is my code for adding the colour to text-box

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    DataRowView drv = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        int iEmpID = Convert.ToInt32(drv["ID"]);

        //e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "location='cliMaintainEEpersonaldetails.aspx?EmpID=" + iEmpID + "'");

        TextBox txb = (TextBox)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("lbl");
        if (txb.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:ChangeRowColor('" + e.Row.ClientID + "','" + iEmpID + "')");
            //txb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.all['" + e.Row.ClientID + "'].style.backgroundColor = ''red';");
            txb.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.previous_color=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#ffffda'");
            //txb.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.previous_color;");
        }
    }

 }
```

Or can i write java script function for this or is it possible to make any changes in existing script.

This is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//variable that will store the id of the last clicked row
var previousRow;

function ChangeRowColor(row,iEmpID)
{
//If last clicked row and the current clicked row are same
if (previousRow == row)
return;//do nothing
//If there is row clicked earlier
else if (previousRow != null)
 document.getElementById(previousRow).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff"; //change the color of the previous row back to white

document.getElementById(row).style.backgroundColor = "#ffffda"; //change the color of the current row to light yellow
//location="Default9.aspx";
//assign the current row id to the previous row id for next row to be clicked

previousRow = row;
//document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_HiddenField1').value = iEmpID ;
}
    </script>
```

Sample images

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use JQuery to attach a click handler to each text input area in the GridView and manage the styling of the cells and inputs from within the handler.

See the following example: http://jsfiddle.net/dYBfU/.

Comment: The GridView control is rendered as a table. From MSDN: [GridView Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) `Displays the values of a data source in a table`. As such the example provided (with a little modification) should provide the functionality you require.

Comment: I know how to handle grid view templates but as per you said how can i have the functionality working for me with out table